# copying rather than modifying a job (APScheduler)

Tags: python-2.7, apscheduler

I'm writing a database-driven application with APScheduler (v3.0.0). Especially during development, I find myself frequently wanting to command a scheduled job to start running **now** without affecting its subsequent schedule.

It's possible to do this at job creation time, of course:

```
def dummy_job(arg):
  pass
sched.add_job(dummy_job, trigger='interval', hours=3, args=(None,))
sched.add_job(dummy_job, trigger=None, args=(None,))
```

However, if I already have a job scheduled with an interval or date trigger...

```
>>> sched.print_jobs()
Jobstore default:
   job1 (trigger: interval[3:00:00], next run at: 2014-08-19 18:56:48 PDT)
```

... there doesn't seem to be a good way to tell the scheduler "make a copy of this job which will start right now." I've tried `sched.reschedule_job(trigger=None)`, which schedules the job to start right now, *but* removes its existing trigger.

There's also no obvious, simple way to duplicate a job object while preserving its `args` and any other stateful properties. The interface I'm imagining is something like this:

```
sched.dup_job(id='job1', new_id='job2')
sched.reschedule_job('job2', trigger=None)
```

Clearly, APScheduler already contains an internal mechanism to copy job objects since repeated calls to `get_job` don't return the same object (that is, `(sched.get_job(id) is sched.get_job(id))==False`).

Has anyone else come up with a solution here? I'm thinking of posting a suggestion on the developers'  site if not.

Answer (score 2):

As you've probably figured out by now, that phenomenon is caused by the job stores instantiating jobs on the fly based on data loaded from the back end. To run a copy of a job immediately, this should do the trick:

```
job = sched.get_job(id)
sched.add_job(job.func, args=job.args, kwargs=job.kwargs)
```